# Condensing Repetitive Excel Userform VBA Code

Tags: vba, excel

I am having Issues with my Macro being to big so I am trying to Condense the code since a lot of it is repetitive.

Here is the main code that is repeated 30 times for 30 different check boxes

```
`If **CheckBox3.Value** = True Then
eRow = Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
Cells(eRow, 7).Value = ComboBox1.Value
    If CheckBox29.Value = True Then
        Cells(eRow, 8).Value = Controls("CheckBox" & 29).Caption
            If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
                Cells(eRow, 14).Value = "Yes"
            Else
                Cells(eRow, 14).Value = "No"
            End If
        Cells(eRow, 15).Value = ComboBox6.Value
        Cells(eRow, 16).Value = ComboBox7.Value
            If CheckBox2.Value = True Then
                Cells(eRow, 17).Value = "Yes"
            Else
                Cells(eRow, 17).Value = "No"
            End If
        Cells(eRow, 18).Value = ComboBox8.Value
        Cells(eRow, 19).Value = TextBox5.Value
        Cells(eRow, 20).Value = TextBox6.Value
        Cells(eRow, 21).Value = TextBox7.Value
        Cells(eRow, 22).Value = TextBox8.Value
        Cells(eRow, 26).Value = TextBox9.Value
        Cells(eRow, 27).Value = TextBox10.Value
    Else
        Cells(eRow, 8).Value = "Sales Call"
        Cells(eRow, 15).Value = "-"
        Cells(eRow, 16).Value = "-"
        Cells(eRow, 18).Value = "-"
        Cells(eRow, 19).Value = "-"
        Cells(eRow, 20).Value = "-"
        Cells(eRow, 21).Value = "-"
        Cells(eRow, 22).Value = "-"
        Cells(eRow, 26).Value = "-"
        Cells(eRow, 27).Value = "-"
        Cells(eRow, 14).Value = "No"
        Cells(eRow, 17).Value = "No"
    End If
Cells(eRow, 9).Value = ComboBox3.Value
Cells(eRow, 10).Value = TextBox2.Value
Cells(eRow, 11).Value = TextBox3.Value
Cells(eRow, 12).Value = TextBox4.Value
Cells(eRow, 13).Value = ComboBox4.Value
Cells(eRow, 23).Value = ComboBox5.Value
**Cells(eRow, 24).Value = Controls("CheckBox" & 3).Caption
  Cells(eRow, 25).Value = TextBox11.Value**
Cells(eRow, 6).Value = TextBox1.Value
End If`
```

The only Items that Change are CheckBox3 and TextBox11 I tried to Bold not sure if it worked.

the values of those mentioned above only change by + 1.

I have tried multiple Dim command and next but I can not get it to work right.

Any help is appreciate it.

Comment: If this code is working, it is off-topic here. Please post it on [Code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put everything in a function and pass the appropriate values to it:

```
If CheckBox3.Value = True Then
    call myFunction (CheckBox3.Caption, textbox11.value)
End if
```

Then call the function again for other checkboxes and textboxes):

```
If CheckBox4.Value = True Then
    call myFunction (CheckBox4.Caption, textbox12.value)
End if
```

the function:

```
myFunction (myCheckboxCaption as string, myTextBoxValue as string)
    eRow = Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    Cells(eRow, 7).Value = ComboBox1.Value
        If CheckBox29.Value = True Then
            Cells(eRow, 8).Value = Controls("CheckBox" & 29).Caption
                If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
                    Cells(eRow, 14).Value = "Yes"
                Else
                    Cells(eRow, 14).Value = "No"
                End If
            Cells(eRow, 15).Value = ComboBox6.Value
            Cells(eRow, 16).Value = ComboBox7.Value
                If CheckBox2.Value = True Then
                    Cells(eRow, 17).Value = "Yes"
                Else
                    Cells(eRow, 17).Value = "No"
                End If
            Cells(eRow, 18).Value = ComboBox8.Value
            Cells(eRow, 19).Value = TextBox5.Value
            Cells(eRow, 20).Value = TextBox6.Value
            Cells(eRow, 21).Value = TextBox7.Value
            Cells(eRow, 22).Value = TextBox8.Value
            Cells(eRow, 26).Value = TextBox9.Value
            Cells(eRow, 27).Value = TextBox10.Value
        Else
            Cells(eRow, 8).Value = "Sales Call"
            Cells(eRow, 15).Value = "-"
            Cells(eRow, 16).Value = "-"
            Cells(eRow, 18).Value = "-"
            Cells(eRow, 19).Value = "-"
            Cells(eRow, 20).Value = "-"
            Cells(eRow, 21).Value = "-"
            Cells(eRow, 22).Value = "-"
            Cells(eRow, 26).Value = "-"
            Cells(eRow, 27).Value = "-"
            Cells(eRow, 14).Value = "No"
            Cells(eRow, 17).Value = "No"
        End If
    Cells(eRow, 9).Value = ComboBox3.Value
    Cells(eRow, 10).Value = TextBox2.Value
    Cells(eRow, 11).Value = TextBox3.Value
    Cells(eRow, 12).Value = TextBox4.Value
    Cells(eRow, 13).Value = ComboBox4.Value
    Cells(eRow, 23).Value = ComboBox5.Value
    Cells(eRow, 24).Value = myCheckboxCaption
    Cells(eRow, 25).Value = myTextBoxValue
    Cells(eRow, 6).Value = TextBox1.Value
End function
```

Comment: Thank you this looks like it would work but how would I get 
"Cells(eRow, 24).Value = Controls("CheckBox" & 3).Caption"
to equal the checkbox # of that Checkbox (ie 3 for 3 4 for 4 5 for 5)?

Comment: You can pass multiple values to a function, see my edited code.

Comment: Sorry for the Repeat Questions just having issues getting it to run, Type Mismatch Error and it points to this line of code

Call myFunction(CheckBox3.Caption, TextBox11.Value)

Comment: Sorry, without thinking, I associated the checkbox caption with a `boolean` variable instead of a `string` (in my mind checkbox = boolean).

Comment: No problem I thought of that but now it is saying Object Required and Points to Cells(eRow, 7).Value = ComboBox1.Value.

Sorry I am new and Teaching myself. this is the first time to ask for help since I could not get it to repeat without just plain old copy paste which made excel have a file to large error.

Comment: Are the correct values shown for those `eRow` and `Combobox1.Value` when you debug? You may also want to step through the code to see exactly what happens

Comment: The code works perfect before I make it a function.

The problem I have is when people on 32Bit Excel get a file is to large and I have to Break it up. I search and saw about condensing code but could never get it to work for my situation. does making it a function require me to rewrite the way to but the Values entered in the userform to the Sheet?